# Why am I not congratulated on my first work-anniversary with my current employer by my manager?

Tags: work-environment

My managers is cced in an email where my employer is recognizing my anniversary and the expectation was that the manager would forward it to the whole team. We might have actually gone for some celebration/party.
But nothing happened as per my expectations.

Is it normal (not a concern)? This happened with me for the first time. I was congratulated by my manager/team, whenever I completed an year with my previous employers.

To clarify again, this question is not about employer, it's about manager/team.

Comment: Maybe your manager has other things to think about or the automated emails are on a folder he doesn't check. Did you mention it innocently during the coffee break ?

Comment: Is this normal where you are from? I've never been congratulated nor do I see a reason to be

Comment: @Twyxz I am from India, where are you from actually (it's difficult to judge from your name sir) ?

Comment: @Answers_Seeker maybe you are right

Comment: Is this your first place of employment where you have spent at least a year there? Had it happened before or been treated as a normal action in other workplaces?

Comment: @kozaky I have more than 7 years of experience and this is my fourth employer. I have been recognized everywhere. May be I was special.

Comment: Do _other_ people at this company get congratulations on their one year? It might just be that this company doesn't care much about it.

Comment: @Erik yes, surely I won't expect if I complete the second anniversary here.

Comment: I have never, ever, seen anyone's "one year anniversary!" mentioned for any reason, at all, ever, having been involved in many businesses on every continent.

Comment: @Fattie come to India, work with Big MNCs (having more than 1 million employees) like TCS, Tech Mahindra, Infosys

Comment: Fair enough, @DeepakMishra, i've never worked AT a huge multinational in India.   I have never, ever, ever seen this in all my other experience in India.  (BTW, you know how much those dudes have to spend on treats at Diwali?   :)   )  Really then I think you know yourself, it is *exceptionally unusual*.  It happens at the 10 big MNCs in India, and that's it.  At no other company on Earth  :)

Comment: I guess it's a difference in culture, my previous experience is with Big India based MNCs and now I am working with US based employer. So need to adjust a lot.

Comment: @Fattie I am not saying that which one are better, I am just saying that I somewhat became used to Indian one, so felt a little bad today :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I work in IT in rural USA, and my supervisor buys cookies to celebrate the one-year anniversary of each new person on our team. Granted, we have a small team, and she's a great supervisor. IT is a competitive field, so doing simple/inexpensive things to make your employees feel appreciated or special isn't completely unheard of. Having said that, I wouldn't feel bad if things were different at my next job, but "At no other company on Earth" is a total exaggeration.

Comment: @Keiki Thanks, I thought I am the alone Abhimanyu here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhimanyu

Comment: They put work anniversaries in the weekly newsletter where I work. Nobody really cares unless you hit the big milestones, then they give you stuff like plaques and such.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have edited the question. Does it clarify now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Companies that care about employees do this. In my view, it all comes down to company culture. The company I worked for, gave me a raise and pen. It was nice. I felt like they liked me and liked me work. I felt like I was now "one of them", because there's a sort of awkward "new guy" period. It's a useful way of including someone into the organization.

[Forbes covers this a bit](https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbeshumanresourcescouncil/2017/09/21/seven-ways-to-integrate-new-hires-and-make-them-feel-welcome-from-the-first-day/#533f7d3940f6).

> 1. Create A Welcoming Environment
>
> New hires don't yet know the cultural norms at your organization. Hopefully this means they'll share lots of ideas, but sometimes people are quiet until they see how others behave. Make sure new talent knows you welcome input and you're excited to hear their point of view in meetings. To be successful, you have to socialize this within the organization, and over time it will become the new norm. -

Making people feel welcome with a small gesture goes a LONG way to making the company stronger. Not doing it, isn't ideal. So the answer to you question:

> Why am I not congratulated on my first work-anniversary with my current employer by my manager?

Is likely the company culture doesn't include this idea OR the manager is busy and will get around to it.

Comment: I liked that "awkward "new guy" period" thing. It happens actually even when we have previous experience. My manager is not busy, he is just like the most people who have commented here, always ready to harass employees and when you ask them few questions they say that you are challenging my integrity. This equals to an harassment case. You might be terminated, blah, blah, blah.

Comment: -1 "Companies that care about employees do this" implies "Companies that don't do this, don't care about a employees", which is laughable.

Comment: @DonFusili your logic is also laughable. If X->Y, that does not necessarily prove Not X ->Not Y.

Comment: @DeepakMishra Indeed, but X -> Y does imply Not Y -> Not X.

Comment: @DonFusili Yes, that implies that company who do not care about employees do not do this. Here X: this and Y: company's care.

Comment: @DeepakMishra The answer says "companies that care about employees" (X) "do this" (->Y). This is equivalent to "Companies that don't do this" (Not Y) "don't care about employees" (-> Not X). This is *not* the same as "Companies that don't care about employees" (Not X) "don't do this" (-> Not Y), which is what you want to hear. I'm sorry that this site is not the echo chamber/spin doctor you long for.

Comment: @DonFusili Don't be judgemental about me and your understanding of the answer (X & Y) is not correct

Answer (score 8):

Does it really matter if someone says "well done, the Earth is in approximately the same position relative to the Sun as when you started here"? Frankly, no - so don't make a fuss about it.

If a year's service means something actually concrete to you like improved employment rights, more leave, a pay rise or whatever then make sure that happens but don't worry about something which makes no real difference to anyone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86362/discussion-on-answer-by-philip-kendall-why-am-i-not-congratulated-on-my-first-wo).

Answer (score 3):

Not all companies mark work anniversaries and perhaps not all managers in companies that do mark them bother. I can't think of one I've worked for that's marked single years.

There have been a couple that have marked significant milestones like 5, 10 or 20 years, but even those have been the minority.

There are probably other reasons why your manager is informed that you've completed a year's service, these could include:

- Your holiday entitlement might change.
- Your employment status might have changed, e.g. from probationary employee to permanent.

Of course, the question of whether the first year anniversary *should* be acknowledged is a different question, and if other managers follow the "protocol" but yours doesn't then that reflects badly on them.

Comment: My managers is cced in an email where my employer is recognising my anniversary and the expectation is that the manager would forward it to the whole team. We might have actually gone for some celebration/party. I got confirmed six months ago. I know this is a small concern, but still it's strong enough to raise a question against their management skills.

Comment: @Deepak, that detail was missing from your question which is why I answered as I did.

Comment: okay makes sense.